# Should we turn the cap the other way?

Tags: feature-request, design

I was noticing something just now around the toolbar.  This is what it looks like for me on the regular site:

[image]

and this is what it looks like for me on the meta site:

[image]

Looking at those pictures, do I have four badges on the regular site and two on the meta site, or do I have 14 badges and 12 badges?  At first I actually had trouble telling, and the reason is that the tail of the cap in the toolbar looks like it could potentially be the number "1".

I recommend potentially moving the tail of the cap from the right to the left.  It shouldn't cause problems with the reputation score in this case, partially because of a much greater margin between the reputation and the graphic, and partially because of different colors between them.

It's possible there may be other places on this site which would have trouble with the tail being on the left, in which case I recommend one of three things: Either alternate which side the tail is on, increase the margin between the cap and the badge count, or just redesign the graphic for the cap.

Comment: This is a fantastic point, well highlighted. I think this is partly an issue of your fonts, though. Just because I imagine UI team will ask... do you have any script blockers or UI changing extensions loaded? Also, browser/machine info?

Comment: @eykanal Thanks, just AdblockPlus really.  This is in Firefox on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: I second @eykanal; for me, the tassel ends well below the line the numbers appear on and it is not easily confused as part of the number.

Answer (score 7):

Since Academia has graduated from beta, it makes sense that the tassel is on the right (looking at it, left if you were under the cap). I propose leaving the tassel as is.

Comment: For those, like me, who have never had to don such a cap: is there a preferred position for the tassel?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - one enters the graduation ceremony with the tassel to the left and, at the appropriate moment everyone switches the tassel over to the right (their left/right) signifying that they are now graduated. No clue when the tradition started...

Comment: And, after receiving an undergraduate degree, the tassel is always worn on the left. This applies both to faculty members (or others) attending the ceremony in regalia, as well as to students receiving higher degrees.